# Google Pixel 3 - Cannot Stop Security Updates

Tags: rooting, ota-update, google-pixel-3-xl

I just recently got the new pixel 3 and have loved the phone from stem to stern but I have this huge issue with it. Since I turned it on and ported all my contacts, photos, etc over it has not loaded all my apps. I found out this was because it has been installing system security updates non-stop for over 24 hours now, rendering it basically useless.

I can't use this phone in this state. I've tried clearing the google app cache and storage and it keeps on chugging through security update to security update. I can't even tell how many it has completed or has yet to do because it has no indication of how many are left, at all. All I can see is the current update's progress. I've had to reboot the phone twice this morning just for the security updates.

Is there a way via rooting the Pixel 3 or entering developer mode, or just some setting i overlooked that I can tell the system to stop updating so I can have a useable phone? Or am I up a creek.

Comment: If it is acting like that, something is wrong with the device. Return it.

Comment: Just find a fast WiFi for your phone and wait. Security updates are released monthly and they need to be installed sequentially. So if your phone is preinstalled with January 2019 version (for example) it needs to install February patch, March patch, and so on... until it catches up.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this this the proper way to initialize a newly bought Android device.

Google usually releases every month a new security update and each security update has to be installed individually, and often after the update installation a restart is required.

Hence if you get a device that for example was produced 6 months before you have to install up to 6 updates one at a time.

In this case the Pixel 3 has been released in October 2018. If the device you got was produced at that time up to the time of the question up to 8 updates have accumulated and each update has to installed one-by-one plus reboot. 
Hence the first hours after switching on a new Android device you are busy installing security updates, which usually requires several buttons to be pressed at the correct time.